# htaccess : redirect non-www to www causes strange characters when parameter contains spaces

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I wrote these rules to redirect non-www to www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It works fine but when I have spaces in url parameters I have same strange characters added il the URL.

*Example* : I have a search form, when I type "foo bar", the generated URL is example.com/?searchword=foo%252520bar&searchphrase=all

If i delete the htaccess rules then there is no more **%2525** in the URL !

what's wrong with the rules ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

`NE` flag will avoid encoding the resulting URL. Make sure to clear your browser cache when you test it.